# No space on New 3ds xl

Tags: pokemon-series, new-nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds-2dsxl

I have a brand new Nintendo New 3DS XL. I have downloaded pokemon AS and the update. There is no room for pokemon X. I have not taken any pictures, only downloaded these games. How do I fix this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The New 3DS and its XL counterpart both offer only 1 GB of storage space. [Pokémon X/Y and Pokémon ORAS require 1.7/1.8 GB respectively](http://www.nintendolife.com/news/2014/09/pokemon_omega_ruby_and_alpha_sapphires_file_size_is_a_bit_of_a_pocket_monster). Obviously, each game is far too large to fit on the 3DS' internal memory.

Fortunately, the New 3DS supports SD cards to extend the console's memory, and ship with 4 GB SD cards by default. However, it's possible that games require more free space to install than they'd occupy in memory. The Wii U, for instance, needs roughly twice the space to download a game, then decompress and install it. This would explain why you could install AS (and its update), but not X.

The only way to fix this, is to buy a bigger SD card and install it into your 3DS. Unlike the original 3DS, the New 3DS supports Micro SD cards instead of the regular ones. Make sure you buy the correct format, or your new purchase won't fit inside your 3DS.

Keep in mind, that although the New 3DS supports SDXC cards (which offer capacities beyond 32 GB), you can't just insert SD cards larger than 32 GB and expect them to work out of the box. SDXC cards with capacities greater than 32 GB are formatted using exFAT, which the 3DS can not read. To use 64 GB cards or greater, you'll need to format your SD card using FAT32 instead.